# ISPmanager API получить количество свободной или занятой физической памяти

Tags: ispmanager, isp

Мне нужно узнать сколько в пользователя осталось или занято физической памяти, такое возможно? API возвращает только информацию о том сколько памяти выделено пользователю всего.

```
https://1.1.1.1:1500/ispmgr?authinfo=name:password&out=xml&func=user.edit&elid=username
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Посмотреть можно либо через mgrctl
/usr/local/mgr5/sbin/mgrctl -m ispmgr userstat elid=<имя юзера>
либо по API
https://1.1.1.1:1500/ispmgr?authinfo=name:password&out=xml&func=userstat&elid=username

переменную userstat использовать нужно, а не user.edit

Comment: Спасибо большое, думал уже что это нельзя сделать. Сколько документаций прочитал о ISP, ничего так и не нашел. А можно ссылку на вашу документацию?)